# GeoPDF Support in GDAL

Tags: gdal, installation, geospatial-pdf

I installed OSGeo4W using a Windows installer... it contains GDAL 1.7.3.  I can't get GDAL to recognize PDF as a file type using commands in MSYS shell.  Does this version of GDAL not support PDFs?  If not, what do I need to do to add support to PDFs for GDAL?

Comment: (Available for GDAL >= 1.8.0) http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html

Comment: Gdalinfo --formats will always show supported formats.

Comment: @mapperz want to make that an actual answer?

Comment: I would if the user responded with some feedback. Was too short for a full answer.